# Delete session and cookies then create new one - only takes effect at next page load

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I use Codeigniter (which may be the reason for my issue) and I identify users by a couple of cookies and session variables. When users want to sign up but are detected like already having an account based on their cookie (e.g someone else signed up on their computer), this is what currently happens in the controller after the signup form has been submitted:

- if detected user #4 already has an account but still signs up: delete
  session and cookies, then create new user-identifying session and
  cookie as user #5 and proceed with the DB stuff.
- else proceed with the DB stuff as user #4.

**The issue**: deleting the session and/or cookie only happens at next page load, which means that I sign user 4 up (overwriting the current user 4) but it becomes user 5 (who has nothing in the DB) as soon as the next page loads. The correct behaviour would be to get the deletion instant, so that when I create the new session + cookie it correctly creates the account for user #5.

How can I delete session variables + cookies instantly, not at next page load?

**UPDATE**:
After some testing this is what happens: cookies don't get deleted before next page load; session variables get deleted instantly but not set before next page load. So 2 different issues to fix so that they both get instantly deleted and set again.

Comment: The problem is even CI sessions are cookies, and those are available only the following request

Comment: simply wipe the session unconditionally in your login page. `if (login == successful) { $_SESSION = array() }`. then it won't matter WHAT was done with the previous user. the new user will get a fresh clean session

Comment: @DamienPirsy I use the DB storage of CI sessions so they're not cookies in my case

Comment: @MarcB the issue is that I use cookies to show some (non-sensitive) data if the user comes back later; and I use the sessions to know whether the user is logged in or not so deleting them after login would log them out automatically... Sessions are deleted after 2h or when they log out but when a user comes back to the site with only a cookie, I create some "low trust" session variables to identify him.

Comment: You cannot set or delete a cookie without a page load, because cookies are set through headers.

Comment: @Cryode there is absolutely no way to do so?

Comment: No, [the user manual explains that](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). You should use CI's DB-based sessions to hold all of your custom data. That way the cookie value doesn't matter, since the cookie only assigns that user to a particular DB session row.

Answer (score 0):

```
detect user
delete cookies
    optionally you could create new session data right here
redirect to some page of your choosing :)
```

that way it will pick it up correctly (and create new data)

Comment: In my case if a user comes I don't know whether that's really them or not yet, until they log in. So if a user comes to the site with a cookie only, I create some session variables, one being the trust as "low". And as long as they don't log in I can't know if it's actually the user or someone else with the old cookie. So when they try to sign up I need to be able to delete session and cookie instantly, not load the page again and then do it (poor user experience).

Comment: no my friend - you are describing "remember me" functionality - it should work as: user leaves cookie behind him, user cames back, system detects that cookie and check in for e.g. database if proper record exists and is valid (browser, system, ip) - if everything is OK you logged user and move on - if anything is wrong you destroy that data (cookies) and redirect to login page

Comment: if as you said user must login so you could change trust from "low" to something else (probably logged user) then you don't need that cookie in first place

Comment: That is how it works till the "if everything is OK you log the user in": in my case the "remember me" is a soft feature for non-sensitive stuff but they need to actually properly log in to be fully trusted as their account has sensitive data e.g their bank details. So I recognise this is the same computer etc. and do a "soft log in" but when they come to sign up and actually fill the form I know they are a new user for sure and then delete everything. And forcing them to log in before they can interact with the site would kill conversion completely.

Comment: I need the cookie to remember some data to show them the equivalent of a price proposal based on their previous search, without having them to fill everything again if they come back to that page after a newsletter or a few days later.

Comment: ok now I get it - but still when you are removing that cookies just do redirect to the same page you are already - it will force system to detect that cookies aren't there anymore

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid. for the user it would be like that: I fill all fields in the signup form, then I get the same form reloaded but no validation error - I would be at a loss to understand what happened as a user and may not press the submit form button again.

Comment: when user enters signup page he doesn't have to see it for you to delete that cookie - when he enters you already know from request that he has done that - so you remove cookie and redirects (by header in php - user see nothing on that stage cause page don't even start rendering) to the same url - in that request you could show the page to user - system will know that this is a new user and user will see the form for the first time - if you cannot do this it means you performing actions after sending output to user (which is bad)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I changed my script to create a new user directly and not rely on cookies or session to identify the user, which means I don't have to worry about when cookies or session variables get deleted.